# MySQL C API fails to error on subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, c

From the mysql terminal:

```
SELECT 1, (SELECT user_id FROM users);
```

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

In C code:

```
ret = mysql_query("SELECT 1, (SELECT user_id FROM users)");
printf("Ret is %d\n", ret); // -->  "Ret is 0"
```

Is this a bug in the mysql C api? I cannot get any error information from this query. Both `mysql_errno()` and `mysql_error()` return nothing. As far as the API is concerned the query ran successfully.

Comment: When you did it from C, were there multiple rows in the `users` table?

Comment: @isaace I don't think he's "trying to do" anything, he's just testing error reporting.

Comment: The issue is that the query is syntactically correct. Whether it gets an error depends on the table contents. If the `users` table has 0 or 1 row, the query succeeds. If it has more than 1 row, it gets an error.

Comment: Correct syntax is not how mysql determines whether or not a query succeeds. SELECT myfunc() fails and it has the correct syntax. The table contents always have > 1 records for this example.

Comment: My point was that some queries fail because of syntax errors, others fail due to dynamic table info.

Comment: I can't think of any other reason why this wouldn't get an error. The mysql terminal interface is most likely written using the C API.

Comment: So you would expect in this case that mysql_query should return a nonzero code? That's what I would expect as well. I could explcitly check for mysql_more_results(), but even then I still don't get a valid errormessage in the mysql struct.

Comment: I did some testing here, the error is reported when you call `mysql_store_result()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error isn't reported until you call `mysql_store_result`.

```
ret = mysql_query(con, "SELECT 1, (SELECT user_id FROM users)");
printf("Ret is %d\n", ret); // -->  "Ret is 0"
MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
if (result == NULL) {
    printf("Error is %s", mysql_error(con); // prints "Subquery returns more than 1 row"
}
```